# How does loeb terminate in this haskell example?

Tags: haskell

From [this *Youtube* video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F7F-BzOB670):

```
> let loeb fs = xs where xs = fmap ($ xs) fs
> loeb [length, (!! 0)]
[2,2]
```

The `xs` here is recursively defined, and how loeb terminates is beyond me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try it:

```
loeb [length, (!! 0)]
= xs where xs = fmap ($ xs) [length, (!! 0)]
= xs where xs = [length xs, xs !! 0]
```

so of course `length xs` is just 2, and so the first element of `xs` (`length xs`) is 2 as well.

*remember*: `length xs` does not need to evaluate the items of the list:

```
length [undefined, undefined] = 2
```

Comment: glorious lazy evaluation.

Answer (score 6):

The reason is that `length` does not evaluate the elements of the list. It simply counts the elements. `length` is (semantically equivalent) defined as:

```
length (_:xs) = 1 + length xs
length _ = 0
```

Even if one of the elements thus comes down on calculating an expression that results in an infinite loop, that doesn't matter. Al long as the list itself is not infinite of course.

Now of you call `loeb [length, (!! 0)]`, it will be evaluated as:

```
loeb [length, (!! 0)]
    xs = fmap ($ xs) [length,(!! 0)]
    xs = [length xs,xs !! 0]
```

Thus the `length xs` performs **lazy evaluation**: it is not interested in the value of the elements, so they remain *unsolved* when counting.